# how to show dynamic listview in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have slider menu on which I use fragments.I want to show list view (json data on list view) on fragment.That's my code

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

    ListView sweepstakes_list;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

         //here I use my code

        return view;
    }
}
```

how do I show dynamic listview in fragments?

Comment: so what is the problem? define your list and set your data to adapter.

Comment: dynamic listview or dynamic data into ListView? What's the issue exactly?

Comment: yes @shayan define list and set your data to adapter but in fragments

Comment: @paresh yes dymanic listview but in fragments

Comment: not different between activity and fragment, first try then if you had problem ask here

Comment: @piyush I tried it from activity but I donot find any solution how I done it from fragments

Comment: @NabeeghArshad There is no much difference betweeen then. You can implement same as implement in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASYNC task.
call async task whenever you want to update your list view.

Comment: ok then use if loop inside the onCreateView set some global variable and change it accordingly.